# Invoke one stored procedure from another stored procedure by passing array values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm unable to pass the array values as input to another stored procedure. However when I try to insert(table kvstore populated without issues) the array values, the table get loaded. Please advice me on how to pass array values dynamically from one stored procedure to another.

The raise notice prints values like below
NOTICE:  Value 1: 
NOTICE:  Value 2:

````
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_schema.test_insert_choice(
    p_member_crn  character varying,
    p_preferencearray text[][],
    p_created timestamp without time zone,
    p_modified timestamp without time zone,
    p_created_system smallint,
    p_created_by character varying,
    p_modified_by character varying,
    p_modified_system smallint
    )
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE     


    lv_n_rtn                INTEGER ; 
    lv_t_err_msg            TEXT ;
    lv_t_err_dtl            TEXT ;


BEGIN   


    /*FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(p_preferencearray, 1) LOOP
        INSERT INTO lcdm_main.kvstore (key, value)
        VALUES (p_preferencearray[i][1], p_preferencearray[i][2]);
    END LOOP;*/

    FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(p_preferencearray, 1) LOOP
    raise notice 'Value 1: %', p_preferencearray[i][1];
    raise notice 'Value 2: %', p_preferencearray[i][2];
        perform  test_schema.test_insert_master(p_member_crn,
                                                         p_preferencearray[i][1],
                                                         p_preferencearray[i][2],
                                                         p_created,
                                                         p_modified,
                                                         p_created_system,
                                                         p_created_by,
                                                         p_modified_by,
                                                         p_modified_system);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 0;

END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution and replacing FOR with FOREACH helped to resolve the issue

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_schema.test_insert_choice(
    p_member_crn  character varying,
    p_preferencearray text[][],
    p_created timestamp without time zone,
    p_modified timestamp without time zone,
    p_created_system smallint,
    p_created_by character varying,
    p_modified_by character varying,
    p_modified_system smallint
    )
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE     

    lv_n_rtn                INTEGER ; 
    lv_t_err_msg            TEXT ;
    lv_t_err_dtl            TEXT ;

       m   text[];
       arr text[] := p_preferencearray;

BEGIN   


   FOREACH m SLICE 1 IN ARRAY arr
   LOOP
       perform  test_schema.test_insert_master(p_member_crn,
                                                         m[1],  --Preference Id
                                                         m[2],  --Preference Value
                                                         p_created,
                                                         p_modified,
                                                         p_created_system,
                                                         p_created_by,
                                                         p_modified_by,
                                                         p_modified_system);
   END LOOP;

    RETURN 0;


END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

Thanks for everyone